# javascript variables in another html page

Tags: javascript, html

Especially I must indicate that I just have been started to developing javascript applications. my problem is that;
I have an html page what includes my map. for example(a.html). Also i have javascript variable inside in this page it is (var map)
My real problem is that i have another html page (b.html) and it includes an iframe which includes a.html. But i need to access my variable (var map) from b.html.
How can I achieve it? is it possible? if it is not how can I solve this problem?

thanx...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. you can use cookie or local database to share data between html files.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty variable in `b.html`

```
var mapCollector;
```

then after you load `a.html` in the `iframe` write your map to that back

```
document.parent.mapCollector = map;
```

or you could iterate through the `iframes` in `b.html` and grab the data that way.
The solution is theoretical as I do not have my environment right now.

Limitation is: both htmls have to come from the same domain.

**EDIT :**

The correct reference is:

```
window.parent.mapCollector = map;
```

Also look on [my test case](http://mikoandras.hu/work/stackoverflow/) for a working solution.

Comment: " The solution is theoretical "  please comment back if this really works ? Curious to know if this works :)

Comment: The solution works, have seen this on pages. I have written "is theoretical" because I do not have my computer right now to give you a correct fiddle with working code. if both pages come from the same domain, you are allowed to access back and forth between them.

Comment: I'm sorry for being misleading, the `window` has the parent reference to the outer html, as in [my test case](http://mikoandras.hu/work/stackoverflow/).

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports HTML5 , you could use localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem('my_key','my_value');
var n = localStorage('my_key');
```

The other alternative would be to use cookies.

So you should check first :

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

More reading: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html